# Provided an image that is available locally already

Tags: android, firebase, react-native

I'm using React Native and Firebase in my app. And out of nowhere I just started recieving this error:
[image]

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input.
at doWrite(_stream_writable.js)
at Promise.resolve.then.then.then.catch.then.message
```

and in my react packager it is pointing to this code:

```
    onProfilesChange = async (snap) => {
    var allProfilePromises = []
    snap.forEach((child) => {
      var profileId = child.val().profileId
      var alreadyAdded = this.state.profiles.some(x => x.id === profileId)

      if (alreadyAdded === false) {
        var profilePromise = this.registerOnProfileChanges(profileId)
        allProfilePromises.push(profilePromise)
      }
    })

    await Promise.all(allProfilePromises)

    var profileCount = snap.numChildren()
    this.setState({ profiles: this.state.profiles, loading: false, profileCount: profileCount })

    if (profileCount <= 0) {
      this.getUserName()
    }
  }
```

which is being run when componentMount is called. Now the error is quite clear, but I don't know WHY it is being produced, nor how to get passed it. This code has worked for months without me changing anything to it.

Thank in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try clearing cache and restart the server...

```
cd android & gradlew clean & cd .. & rm -rf node_modules/ & npm cache clean --force & yarn install & react-native run-android
```

you may want to use `npm i` instead of `yarn install`

Answer (score 1):

I met the same problem. It is relevant to image.
I solved this by changing the version of react-native-img-cache.
run this:
        npm install react-native-img-cache@1.4.0